# Форма связи и копиями полей

Tags: php, html, form

Возможно не правильно задал вопрос. Можно ли как-то сделать форму, чтобы при заполнении и отправке происходила отправка письма и тут же появлялось всплывающее окно, где часть полей уже заполнена из прошлой формы, было несколько дополнительных. Подскажите в какую хотя бы примерно как это можно организовать. Спасибо

Comment: можно больше конкретно описать? Дать пример имеющегося кода, каким методом(`post`, `get`) отправляется форма, каким способом(обычным или через `ajax`), всплывающее окно подгружается или уже имеется на странице но скрыто...

Comment: Обычный бутстрап, ajax есть скрипт из паблика. Форма тоже есть, она скрыта https://vk-book.ru/prostaya-forma-obratnoj-svyazi-na-php-i-ajax/ сам скрипт